# remove/disable node from icinga2

Tags: monitoring, icinga2

I feel terrible about that I can't solved that alone.

I have an icinga 2.6 installed, 1 master, multiple "slave". One of our server is going to be offline for a longer time so I want to disable/remove the node.

I tried "icinga2 node remove", but I get "deprecated read changelog" error. I read the changelog, but I really can't understand why I need to reverse engineer such an easy functionality across the half internet and read already more ticket then I want...

Still no solution. I tried deleting files from the repository.d but 0 success.

Any help would be good, and some word in the official docs would be nice too :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure if this is the answer you'll be looking for, but I'm giving it a shot anyways as I'm in the same boat as you are.

The only alternative I've found thus far is installing and setting up the module 'Director' on Icinga Web 2. The process is, as everything else with Icinga, poorly documented but it'll get you there. Please see here for instructions: https://www.icinga.com/docs/director/latest/doc/02-Installation/

Once installed, the module needs to be configured and old hosts may be imported. That's where it ended for me: what was documented didn't work and the error messages are probably only logical to the one that wrote them.

I've given up and am looking for a replacement to Icinga2 right now. While I liked it at the start, though it was complicated, they've now gone above and beyond creating a tool that is simply so difficult to work with that many won't.

Answer (score 2):

I have 2.6 installed and needed to remove a node as well.

I know you tried to remove files and that didn't work for you - but it worked for me - so just documenting the process here in case it helps someone else.

I was able to remove the node manually by removing all files and directories related to the node in repository.d, specially in directories:

```
/etc/icinga2/repository.d/endpoints
/etc/icinga2/repository.d/hosts
/etc/icinga2/repository.d/zones
```

Note that in `/etc/icinga2/repository.d/hosts` there should be a subdirectory related to the node you are trying to remove - which also needs to be removed.

Once all are removed (recommend just moving to another location outside of /etc/icinga2 in case you need to revert), restart the icinga2 process.

At this point my icinga2 instance restarted successfully and the node was not showing up anymore.

Answer (score -2):

Well the you need to do the next:

1. Execute: icinga2 node remove 'PC-name'
2. Will appear: deprecated read changelog
3. Then execute: icinga2 node  update-config
4. And the last step: service icinga2 restart
5. Be happy, the node disappear